# R: ggplot set ylim with custom break

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to customize the gap (breaks) in the y axis of the plot. I tried two options.

```
option1: ylim(0.0,0.6) 
option2: scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0, 0.6, 0.1))
```

Problem with the option1 is that it breaks in every 0.2 up to limit of y axis which is 0.6.
[image: Example of problem1]
Problem with the option2 is that it gives this illusion of drastic difference between plots since it enlarge the 0.1 segment of the plot. 
[image: Example of problem2]

What I want is y-axis to be break at every 0.1 or customize it to any break while showing the max limit of the y-axix (in this case 0.0 to 0.6 but break every 0.1).

```
xVal = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
a = c(0.18340368127959822, 0.17496531617798133, 0.16772886654445848, 0.15934821062512169, 0.15390913489444036, 0.14578798884106348, 0.14524174121702108, 0.13958093302847951, 0.1365009715515553, 0.13337340345559975, 0.12995175856952607, 0.12583603207983862, 0.12180656145228715, 0.11824179486798418, 0.11524630600365712)
b = c(0.13544353787855531, 0.11345498050033079, 0.11449834060237293, 0.10479213576778054, 0.09677430524414686, 0.091990671548439179, 0.089965934807318487, 0.088711600335474206, 0.088923403079789909, 0.087989321310275717, 0.085424600757017272, 0.08251334730889931, 0.080178280060313953, 0.077717041621392688, 0.076638743116633837)
c = c(0.087351324973658093, 0.12113308515702567, 0.11422800742900453, 0.11264309199970789, 0.11390287790920843, 0.10774426268894192, 0.10587704437111881, 0.10474954948318291, 0.10568277685778472, 0.10201545270338952, 0.09939827283775747, 0.098062403381144761, 0.094110034623398231, 0.091211408116407641, 0.089369778116029489)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df = data.frame(xVal, a, b, c)
df.melt = melt(df, id="xVal")
```

problem1:

```
ggplot(data=df.melt, aes(x=xVal, y=value, colour=variable)) +
            geom_point() + 
            geom_line() + 
            xlab("xVal") + ylab("YValues") + xlim(1,16) +  
            ylim(0.0,0.6)
```

problem2:

```
ggplot(data=df.melt, aes(x=xVal, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
            geom_point() + 
            geom_line() + 
            xlab("xVal") + ylab("YValues") + xlim(1,16) + 
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0, 0.6, 0.1))
```

How do I customize the y-axis such that break according to a value that I specify.

Comment: Do you also want the `limits` argument in option 2

Comment: Yes, add `+ ylim(0, 0.6)` or the parameter `limits = c(0, .6)` to your scale.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the below.  You need to set both the breaks AND the limits.  Otherwise you may not like the breaks chosen or it may zoom in on the data and not show some of your breaks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

xVal = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
a = c(0.18340368127959822, 0.17496531617798133, 0.16772886654445848, 0.15934821062512169, 0.15390913489444036, 0.14578798884106348, 0.14524174121702108, 0.13958093302847951, 0.1365009715515553, 0.13337340345559975, 0.12995175856952607, 0.12583603207983862, 0.12180656145228715, 0.11824179486798418, 0.11524630600365712)
b = c(0.13544353787855531, 0.11345498050033079, 0.11449834060237293, 0.10479213576778054, 0.09677430524414686, 0.091990671548439179, 0.089965934807318487, 0.088711600335474206, 0.088923403079789909, 0.087989321310275717, 0.085424600757017272, 0.08251334730889931, 0.080178280060313953, 0.077717041621392688, 0.076638743116633837)
c = c(0.087351324973658093, 0.12113308515702567, 0.11422800742900453, 0.11264309199970789, 0.11390287790920843, 0.10774426268894192, 0.10587704437111881, 0.10474954948318291, 0.10568277685778472, 0.10201545270338952, 0.09939827283775747, 0.098062403381144761, 0.094110034623398231, 0.091211408116407641, 0.089369778116029489)

df = data.frame(xVal, a, b, c)
df.melt = melt(df, id="xVal")

ggplot(data=df.melt,
  aes(x=xVal, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line() + xlab("xVal") + ylab("YValues") + xlim(1,16) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0, 0.6, 0.1), limits=c(0, 0.6))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also cleanup on the typos

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution, especially if you want to use custom limits.
From the documentation of scale_y_continuous: breaks can be "A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output".

So if you set the limits, you can just add:

```
custom_lims = c(0, 0.6)
... + scale_y_continuous(breaks=function(lims) {seq(lims[1], lims[2], 0.1)}, limits = custom_lims)
```